# Joining two xarray Datasets by value

Tags: join, dataset, python-xarray

I'm trying to implement a kind of SQL-like join operation on xarray Dataset with different dimensions, but I can't seem to make use of any of the available methods.

A roughly equivalent SQL query would be:

```sql
SELECT ds1.*, ds2.var4 FROM ds1 LEFT JOIN ds2 ON ds1.var1=ds2.var3
```

Is that at all possible with xarray?

A minimal example:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds1 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "var1": (("x", "y"), [[1, 2], [3, 4]]),
        "var2": (("x", "y"), [[5, 6], [7, 8]]),
    },
    coords={"x": [0, 1], "y": [0, 1]},
)

ds2 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "var3": (("z",), [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
        "var4": (("z",), [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]),
    },
    coords={"x": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
)
```

I'd like to make a new dataset that should look like this:

```py
new_ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "var1": (("x", "y"), [[1, 2], [3, 4]]),
        "var2": (("x", "y"), [[5, 6], [7, 8]]),
        "var4": (("x", "y"), [[10, 20], [30, 40]]),
    },
    coords={"x": [0, 1], "y": [0, 1]},
)
```

So, for every value of `var1`, the corresponding value of `var3` tells us which `var4` value to take.